# Displaying rest api response data in react

Tags: reactjs, rest

Here response data contains{name ,details} fields. I have a upload button to upload single/multi files. After uploading files, I don't refresh the page. Now for ex, I upload single file and displayed the response. Again I upload 2 files. Now I should be able to display response of current upload as well as previous one. It should be in the following format:
1.Name1
  Details1
2. Name2
  Details2
3. Name3
 Details 3

```
          this.state.list = this.state.list.concat(details);
          this.state.list_name = this.state.list_name.concat(name);

             < form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <label>
                    Upload a file: <br /><br />
                    <input type="file" name="file" multiple onChange{this.onChangeHandler}/>
                </label>
                <br /><br />
                <button type="submit">
                    Upload</button>
            </form >
            <ol>
               // {this.state.list_name.map((k) =>
                 //   <li>{k} :</li>)}
                //{this.state.list.map((k) =>
                //    <li>{k}</li>

               // )} 
             </ol>


     handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

       const formData = new FormData();
       for (var x = 0; x < this.state.selectedFile.length; x++) {
        formData.append('inputFile', this.state.selectedFile[x])

        fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({

                     details: res.data.details,
                    name: res.data.name
                })
                console.log("res data", res)
                //console.log("Data is", res.data.name) //displays name in the console
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('ERROR message'))
    }
  };
```

I have commented the code that I have tried. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

remove this

```
this.state.list = this.state.list.concat(details);
this.state.list_name = this.state.list_name.concat(name);
```

add this

```
fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
            .then((res) => {
                const list = this.state.list;
                list.concat(res.data.details);
                const list_name = this.state.list_name;
                list_name.concat(name);
                this.setState({
                     list,
                     list_name,
                     details: res.data.details,
                     name: res.data.name
                })
                console.log("res data", res)
                //console.log("Data is", res.data.name) //displays name in the console
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('ERROR message'))
    }
```

Comment: Above code displays data in this format: 1.name1 2.detail1, 3.name2 4.details2. becacuse I'm using :<ol>
               // {this.state.list_name.map((k) =>
                 //   <li>{k} :</li>)}
                //{this.state.list.map((k) =>
                //    <li>{k}</li>

               // )} 
             </ol>  code. Is it possible to display the data like this: 1.name1:detail1, 2.name2:detail2 ?

Comment: or Is it possible to store data like b= (key,value) pair?Here  name as a key and details as a value..

Comment: yes it is possible 
`{this.state.list_name.map((k,index) =>
                 <li>{k} : this.state.list[index]</li>)}`

Comment: Thank u very much..!